# Why do I get database error when I log into my updated ee site

Tags: ee2, database, ee2-upgrades

I wondered if you could help.

I updated my local site to new ee 2.7 and that went swell. I pushed up my files to the server and I can get the /admin.php login page but when I press login i get this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'used' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `exp_security_hashes` SET `used` = 1 WHERE `used` = 0 AND `hash` = '04ec7161468a13c61c984f39f646a76073bdab56' AND `session_id` = 0 AND `date` > 1381249552

Filename: core/EE_Security.php

Line Number: 169
```

Has anyone ever come across this from updating the ee cms before?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

When you upgraded to 2.7, do you recall the first time you accessed admin.php seeing the upgrade screen? And once the upgrade was complete, removing the installer directory?

It sounds like your db has not been upgraded. For example, open your db and check exp_security_hashes table for the 'used' column. Sounds like it is missing. Could be others things missing too if upgrade wasnt completed.

Did you follow these [instructions](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html)

Comment: Hey, Yeah I deleted the install directory. Should I push that back up to my live site version and update from there again or should I just add a new column 'used' in the db?

Comment: dadonbike, do you think thats the best route then?

Comment: I asked you four questions...1) When you upgraded to 2.7, do you recall the first time you accessed admin.php seeing the upgrade screen? - Oh and did you run it successfully? 2) And once the upgrade was complete, remove the installer directory? 3) is the used column missing 4) did you follow the upgrade instructions. I only see two answers from you.

Comment: okay 1) yes on my local version but not on live 2) yes 3) in my db it was missing yes so I added it myself 4) yes I followed them by the book

Comment: You need to run the upgrade on the live site as well, unless you have copied your db from local to live.

Comment: yeah thats what I did on the live site and it still gave me the same error as above and when I did that I looked i the db and exp_security_hashes table had not changed at all? Its weird unless I am doing it all wrong?!

Comment: Open expressionengine/config/config.php. If it doesnt say app_version = 2.7 your upgrade didnt work or wasnt run.

Comment: yeah update worked. I am getting all sorts of errors at the moment. http://www.arcadiaportal-beta.co.uk

Comment: On your live site, is app_version = 2.7?

Comment: Yes, I have logged in now and it seems to be looking at the correct version

Comment: Are you ok then?

Comment: well I can login which is good, I just cannot go to any pages on the site, none of the multi site pages work at all and I get errors about safecracker when I try and go into add-ons-fieldtypes. It must be the update thats causing issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10963/discussion-between-dadonbike-and-m-dunbavan)

Answer (score 3):

Since your files transferred just fine, it's the database export/import process that failed you.

If you are transferring a database from one server to another it is ideal to do one or both of the following:

1. Export the database you are duplicating with DROP TABLES syntax and gzipped. If you don't add DROP tables syntax, you'll just merge the tables possibly leaving unnecessary tables and columns in the replaced database.
2. Before importing the above gzipped database to the second server, delete the second server database's tables completely. The DROP TABLES syntax will remove tables if they already exist before re-adding them, but you may have other tables that are not in the new database.